# How much has the apparent magnitude of the Sun changed?

Tags: the-sun, apparent-magnitude

Did the apparent magnitude of the Sun change in the past 1000 years or so? If so, for what reasons?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak. Absolutely correct.  I assumed questioner was looking for a variation due to the sun itself.  A bad assumption on my part. I will update my answer after I determine difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The apparent magnitude of the sun is constant to within 0.2%  How long it has been that way is only speculation since measurements aren't available. 1000 years is a very short time period in the life cycle of a star. Its safe to say yes its been constant for 1,000 years. There is a small variation based on the 11 year sun spot cycle but this variation is reported at less than 0.1%. There is also a larger variation due to the difference in Earth-to-Sun distance caused by the earths elliptical orbit. This effect is about 7%. This is no due to the sun but rather due to the eccentricity of Earths orbit. There are also minor effects with a cycle time or much greater than 1,000 years. These also due to variations in Earths orbit.

Comment: Don't discount the variation due to Earth's orbit eccentricity.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak. Absolutely correct.  I assumed questioner was looking for a variation due to the sun itself.  A bad assumption on my part. I will update my answer after I determine difference.

Comment: Could you add how the brightness of the Sun 1000 years ago is known?

Comment: I stated it was only speculation really.